# In an android service used to scan for a Bluetooth signal is it necessary to run the code in another thread?

Tags: android, service, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm developing an app that continuously scans for a low energy Bluetooth(BLE) signal using the Android Beacon Library in a service.
The service is always running in the background even if the app isn't running, and it's also running when the app is running.

Is it necessary to use new threads, ExecutorService, to run the code or is that just for operations that take long periods of time and therefore make the UI unresponsive?

Comment: The "onDeviceScanned" callback will be processed on the main thread by default. If you have many of those callbacks, it might be wise to do it on a different thread

Answer (score 0):

No. The BLE apis are not blocking the thread but report results with callbacks.